# How to convert Raycast 3D to 2D in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am a beginner to Unity. I recently completed a live training by unity i.e. "Jewel Miner" (3D). I tried to replicate it in 2D but after conversion it is not working properly.

**Original code from 3D training:**

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 down = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down);

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, down, out hit, 100))
    {
        claw.SetActive(true);
        clawScript.ClawTarget(hit.point);
    }
```

**This is what I converted:**

```
Vector2 down = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.down);
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y), down, 100);

if(hit){
claw.SetActive(true);
clawScript.ClawTarget(hit.point);
}
```

Comment: RaycastHit2D + Physics2D.Raycast. You should have posted the converted code that doesn't work too.

Comment: You'll need a sprite collider for this to work in 2D as each system uses a different part of the engine and don't interoperate. They also work in different fashion as 3D returns bool and 2D returns Raycast2D struct object. So in the second case you'd have to check in the struct if null or not https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html In the docs, they check for the collider.